# Eclipse GDB running inside Chroot environment

Tags: eclipse, gdb, qemu, chroot, gdbserver

I'm currently able to source level debug a remote ARM board by running GDBserver on the board itself (Angstrom Linux) and running GDB inside my qemu environment using Chroot.  Is there a way to do this in Eclipse (Eclipse itself isn't inside the chroot environment)?  I'm currently using that as a development environment and it would be very useful to be able to launch the debugger from there, as well as access source code and set breakpoints inside of Eclipse.